# PHPExcel array to CSV, other encoding

Tags: php, csv, encoding, phpexcel

please help me with PHPExcel.

This code I use for save array to CSV file.

```
$csv = new \PHPExcel();
$csv->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$csv->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($impD['dat'], null, 'A1',true);
$objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($csv, 'CSV');
$objWriter->setEnclosure('');
$objWriter->save($pathFile);
```

PHPExcel save file CSV with coding UTF-8.

I need that PHPExcel save this file CSV with encoding Latin2(iso-8859-2), it goes?

Thanks you

Comment: Then you'll need to create your own Writer to handle changing the charset because the PHPExcel CSV Writer simply does not have this functionality

Comment: But if all you're using PHPExcel for is writing an array to a csv file, why? You should be using PHP's built-in `fputcsv()` function for a simple task like that, and then you have absolute control over the charset that you're saving anyway

Comment: Reasons for PHPExcel CSV is simple.
I need XLSX file to import into MS SQL and other way than through the CSV, I could not find it.
If I create a CSV through fputcsv () so I set to MSSQL DB not imported.
But when I use the CSV PHPExcel so I CSV to MSSQL DB fine imported?

I do not know how else to solve XLSX import data into MSSQL through PHP?
These are files in the range of 1.000 to 130.000 lines.

Thanks